# GoLang 1.6 - HTTPS EOF error

Tags: http, go

I'm currently attempting to debug an issue with issuing a HTTP POST via GoLang 1.6.

The connection is failing with an 'EOF' error.

The test client code: https://gist.github.com/fatmcgav/35d1a4fbd74c7208f445c487f756a5e1

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/tls"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    const body = "{\"auth\":" +
        "{\"identity\":" +
        "{\"methods\":[\"password\"]," +
        "\"password\":" +
        "{\"user\":{\"name\":\"xxx\"," +
        "\"password\":\"xxx\"," +
        "\"domain\":{\"name\":\"xxx_domain\"}" +
        "}" +
        "}" +
        "},\"scope\":{\"project\":" +
        "{\"domain\": " +
        "{\"name\":\"xxx_domain\"},\"name\":\"xxx\"}}}}"

    // Unmarshall JSON
    var m map[string]interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &m)
    // fmt.Println("%v", m)

    var req *http.Request
    var resp *http.Response
    var dump []byte
    var err error
    client := &http.Client{}

    url := "https://identity.xxx/v3/auth/tokens"

    fmt.Println("Requesting auth token against URL: %s", url)

    rendered, err := json.Marshal(m)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error marshalling body: %q", err)
        os.Exit(2)
    }

    req, err = http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewReader(rendered))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Got an error: %q", err)
        os.Exit(2)
    }

    // Need to Close connection
    req.Close = true

    fmt.Println("Setting Insecure TLS mode")
    // Configure custom TLS settings.
    config := &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}
    transport := &http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: config,
        DisableKeepAlives:  true,
        DisableCompression: true,
    }
    client.Transport = transport

    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")

    dump, err = httputil.DumpRequestOut(req, true)
    fmt.Printf("Outgoing requst = \n%q\n", dump)

    resp, err = client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error encountered: %q", err)
    }
    dump, err = httputil.DumpResponse(resp, true)
    fmt.Printf("Response = \n%q\n", dump)
}
```

and resultant output is here:

```
 ~/golang/scripts  go build req-test.go && ./req-test
Requesting auth token against URL: %s https://identity.xxx/v3/auth/tokens
Setting Insecure TLS mode
Outgoing requst =
"POST /v3/auth/tokens HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: identity.xxx\r\nUser-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Length: 262\r\nAccept: application/json\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip\r\n\r\n{\"auth\":{\"identity\":{\"methods\":[\"password\"],\"password\":{\"user\":{\"domain\":{\"name\":\"BusinessSupport_domain\"},\"name\":\"xxx\",\"password\":\"xxx\"}}},\"scope\":{\"project\":{\"domain\":{\"name\":\"xxx_domain\"},\"name\":\"xxx\"}}}}"
Error encountered: %q Post https://identity.xxx/v3/auth/tokens: EOF
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x13659e]

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x338980, 0xc82000a170)
        /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:464 +0x3e6
net/http/httputil.DumpResponse(0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/httputil/dump.go:285 +0x42e
main.main()
        /Users/gavinw/golang/scripts/req-test.go:77 +0xdc
```

For obvious reasons, I've anonymised some of the details..

Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong..

Cheers
Gavin

Comment: The server is closing the connection before you get a response. The panic is because you're reading from the response after the error.

Comment: @JimB OK - Well I can run the same POST test using Curl and get a valid response back...  
So it's either a very strange web-server config, or a Golang issue...

Comment: If it is the server cutting you off, it can be hard to diagnose without server-side logs. I've seen strange things with broken tls implementations, and you could try running github.com/jbardin/gotlsscan to see what tls versions and ciphers are supported (though I don't think this will give you much more info). You could try to force the same tls version and cipher that curl is using, or one where you can decode the request in wireshark. Maybe there's a partial response, and you can check the response headers for info without dereferencing the Body.

Comment: @JimB cheers again for the response... I've put a support req in with the team responsible for the server side, and am waiting on feedback... Using gotlsscan didn't turn up anything useful, other than every protocol fails with 'EOF'... So it definitely seems to be something about a GoLang client talking to the service :s